# Odoo Onchange function not on sale.order.line

Tags: python, odoo

I added a field "Unit Price" to the Quotation Template on Odoo 14. I want to change the Sale Order Line price_unit once the Unit Price in the Quotation Template changes. This seems not to work. Any suggestions

```py
from odoo import api, fields, models, _

class QuotationTemplateCustom(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order.template.line"

    unit_price = fields.Float(string="Unit Price")

class UnitPriceChange(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order.line"
    quotation_template_custom_id = fields.Many2one("sale.order.template.line", string="Quotation Template Custom")
    price_unit = fields.Float(string="Unit Price")

    @api.onchange('quotation_template_custom_id')
    def onchange_quotation_template_custom_id(self):
        self.price_unit = self.quotation_template_custom_id.unit_price
```

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The `onchange_quotation_template_custom_id` method will be called when `quotation_template_custom_id` field is changed, not when the Unit Price in the Quotation Template changes.